# if the exceptions have been swallowed, how does the spring aop log the exceptions' messages?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Here is my example bellow

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    try {
        int i = 1/0;
        System.out.println(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //the exception have been swallowed.

    }
}
```

and  the problem is spring aop's AfterThrowing can't work for this. if i remove the try-catch block.it works well then.  how can i solve this problem. thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's unclear from question what you intend to achieve but this is the intended behavior of `@AfterThrowing` advice.

From [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-advice-after-throwing) -

> After throwing advice runs when a matched method execution exits by throwing an exception.

which means that the advice will be executed only if an exception is thrown from method. In your sample the the exception is consumed and method exits normally thus no advice execution occurs.

Comment: so there is no way to solve this problem according to your description?

Comment: Yes, it's the intended behavior of Spring AOP. The only thing you could do is re-throw it from catch block